# Compiling with maximum debugging symbols and lowest optimizations still skips pieces of code

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Clone emacs repository

  - `git clone https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs.git`
- Run the boiler-plate programs to prepare to build/create Makefiles

  - `i@user:~/emacs$ ./autogen.sh; ./configure`
- Navigate to directory `lib-src/` to build `etags` binary

  - `cd lib-src/`
- Make sure that I am compiling the `etags` binary with maximum debugging symbols with the least amount of optimizations possible by editing the `Makfile` in the `lib-src/` directory

  - `CC=gcc`
  - `CFLAGS=-fno-eliminate-unused-debug-types -g3 -O0`
  - `CPPFLAGS =`
  - `LDFLAGS =`
- Build the `etags` binary target

  - `make tags`
- Test out that no code is skipped while debugging by just doing a simple test run in `gdb` with the arguments like so: `etags --help`

```
gdb etags
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x37ca: file etags.c, line 1071.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/i/emacs/lib-src/etags 
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdfb8) at etags.c:1071
1071    {
(gdb) n
1078      bool help_asked = false;
(gdb) n
1083      progname = argv[0];
(gdb) n
1084      nincluded_files = 0;
(gdb) n
1085      included_files = xnew (argc, char *);
(gdb)
```

As you can see gdb skips lines 1072-1077 which corresponds to the following code:

```c
// ...
// ...
// ...
int                             // Line 1069
main (int argc, char **argv)    // Line 1070
{                               // Line 1071
  int i;                        // Line 1072
  unsigned int nincluded_files; // Line 1073
  char **included_files;        // Line 1074
  argument *argbuffer;          // Line 1075
  int current_arg, file_count;  // Line 1076
  linebuffer filename_lb;       // Line 1077
  bool help_asked = false;      // Line 1078
  ptrdiff_t len;                // Line 1079
  char *optstring;              // Line 1080
  int opt;                      // Line 1081
// ...
// ...
// ...
```

Am I missing something? Should I be adding a flag that ensures that no lines of code be skipped when generating debugging symbols?

Comment: To truly understand this, you need to look at the assembly code. You'll find that there's a function prologue that allocates enough stack space for all of the variables (typically by subtracting a pre-computed value from the stack pointer). So there just isn't any code for a line like 1072. The memory for `i` is allocated in the function prologue, along with the memory for every other variable (lines 73 to 77, and 79 to 81). Line 78 is the only line that actually does something (other than declaring a variable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Yes: lines 1072-1077 are declarations, and the compiler doesn't emit *any* executable code for them.

The way `next` works is: single-step the program one instruction at a time, until current line does not match current line at the start of `next` execution (that is, if you are currently stopped on line X, single step until current line != X), then stop.

Since there are no instructions to stop on that correspond to any lines between 1072 and 1077, single-stepping once immediately gets you to line 1078.

This is working as designed.